# Intuitive name for union of events in probability

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, terminology

***Update: cross-posted to [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547852/word-for-compound-event-at-least-one-of-these-events-will-happen).***

In probability, we often consider unions, intersections, and complements of events. While they can be named as such, it would be nice to have a nice informal/intuitive/non-jargony name for these events that reflects their status as *things that happen*, rather than just subsets of a sample space (other than the direct description "$A \cup B$ means the event "$A$ happens or $B$ happens", "$A \cap B$" means the event "$A$ and $B$ both happen", "$A^c$" means "$A$ doesn't happen"). I'm thinking of this in the context of explaining probability to someone else,

Complement is easy as I can just describe it as the *opposite* of an event. The *opposite* of event $A$ happening, is event $A$ not happening, which is just $A^c$. Makes sense.

For the intersection of two events, I came up with their *coincidence,* which resonates on multiple levels and even has a good verb form: events $A$ and $B$ *coincide* iff their coincidence $A \cap B$ happens iff $A$ and $B$ both happen. (I'm using *equality* in the case where $A$ and $B$ are actually the same event i.e. describe the same set of outcomes, so there's little risk of confusion.)

The union of two events, though, is harder to come up with a good informal name for. Terms like *umbrella*, *compass*, *ambit*, *scope*, *range*, *orbit*, *menu* which describe a list of possible selections sound weird when phrased as events that happen: "the umbrella of $A$ or $B$ happens if..." I thought of terms like *participation*, *intervention*, *intrusion*, *inclusion*, but these all have (literally) unwanted overtones and/or make the events sound personified in a weird way. *Occurrence* and *instance* sound better to describe "at least one of these events happens" but have the drawback that they apply to single events; there's no necessary reason for them to apply to a union of multiple events. *Concurrence* sounds like another description for intersection, as does *conjunction*, which is too jargony. *Disjunction* is also too jargony and sounds like "$A$ or $B$ but not both". *Option* and *choice* imply that someone in particular is picking which event happens.

The least-bad idea that I came up with for union is **alternative**: the *alternative* of $A$ or $B$ happens iff $A \cup B$ happens iff at least one of $A, B$ happens. Could not be used as a verb ("$A$ or $B$ alternate"??) but implies two or more possibilities without also implying that someone is picking which event happens, or that the events are like people "participating" or "intruding". ***Does anyone have a better one?***

Comment: Why not say "$A$ or $B$ happens"? You mention it as an option but don't say why this most natural (IMO) choice does not satisfy you?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Because it's less wordy to have a name for $A \cup B$ as its own event, rather than repeating its definition every time. The same reason we have a separate word for "the union of two sets $A$, $B$" rather than "the set of all elements that are members of either $A$ or $B$".

Comment: Then simply "union event" or "union"? I personally pronounce $P(A \cup B)$ as 'the chance that $A$ or $B$ occurs' when teaching e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma IMO there should be a term for $A \cup B$ considered as its own event the way there is a term "union" for $A \cup B$ considered as its own set, that reflects what $A \cup B$ means *as an event* the way "union" reflects what $A \cup B$ means *as a set*. To me, "union event" doesn't cut it. I'm aware that there are workarounds for this gap in terminology, but I would rather fill the gap than work around it.

Comment: I don't  make a distinction beween a set and an event (they're the same). So I'd just stick to union. An event is just a another name for a subset of the universe of outcomes after all.

Comment: If you want to take the completely formalistic attitude, an “event” in a “sample space” isn’t a subset of a set, any more than an “ideal” in a “ring” is a subgroup of a group. One has more structure than the other. Informally, we speak of “events”, “outcomes”, and “sample spaces” rather than subsets, elements, and sets for interpretative reasons. Why not give corresponding names to unions and intersections when the subsets are events?

Comment: People (mathematicians) invent names for things when usage suggests that (new) names are necessary. I think your question is moot unless/until you can convince us that having a new name for "union" in a probabilistic context would provide enough benefit to be worth the effort of learning it.

Comment: @Henno Thats not true. not every subset of a set is an event. the elements of the sigma alvebra are. you need to define that first. of course you could define the discrete algebra, but in the gemeral case it does not hold.

Comment: The difficulty here is that in ordinary English usage, "or" as in "$A$ or $B$" generally means "either $A$ or $B$ but not both". While not a single word, the phrase "at least one of $A$ and $B$" captures the exact meaning $A\cup B$, and has the ready advantage of extensibility: the meaning of $A\cup B \cup C \cdots$ is captured exactly by the phrase "at least one of $A,B,C \cdots$".

Comment: @Garmekain I had that in mind as well, not every subset of a sample space is an event, just like not every additive subgroup of a ring corresponds to an ideal.

Comment: @EthanBolker Disagree, people (mathematicians) invent names for things when usage suggests that (new) names **would be useful**. Strictly speaking, you never *need* to invent a name for any concept that you can talk about in a definition. We don't "need" to name "unions" of sets, for example; but it simplifies the exposition to not write out the definition of a union each time.

Comment: @RiversMcForge Why would it?